# retrieve php server session timeout

Tags: php, session

I want to retrieve the value of `session.gc_maxlifetime` from the PHP server settings ( the time after which the session expires after no activity ). 
Very important : I do not want to change it, I only wish to retrieve its value ( maybe the value is different from server to server ) and I want to use a PHP script that I made to warn users properly, depending on the settings of those server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 40):

That's where `ini_get`  function comes in hand:

```
$maxlifetime = ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");
```

From manual we read:

> **session.gc_maxlifetime** *integer*
>   session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up. Garbage collection may occur during session start (depending on session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor).

Comment: Input in putty `php -r 'echo ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime"), "\n";'`
It seems the default value is 1440(secs) and it means 24 mins.

Answer (score 2):

`session.gc_maxlifetime` is not  the time after which the session expires after no activity. gc here may be mean garbage collenction.
As the php [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) says,

> session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which
>   data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up. Garbage
>   collection may occur during session start (depending on
>   session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor).
>
> Note: If different scripts have different values of
>   session.gc_maxlifetime but share the same place for storing the
>   session data then the script with the minimum value will be cleaning
>   the data. In this case, use this directive together with
>   session.save_path.

For more refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270960/6521116).