# PHP session time left

Tags: php

I need to get the remaining time for a session until expiration. I know sessions work by garbage collection & the max lifetime is not very accurate but i need a way to detect when a session will expire.

from:[retrieve php server session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796492/retrieve-php-server-session-timeout)

```
$maxlifetime = ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");
```

returns:
1440

interesting post: [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Comment: iv'e been up for 48 hours straight, so i might be over thinking this a little to much.

Comment: @C.Liddell so what you are saying is that i should create a SESSION variable less than 1440 seconds that will be the expire time?

Comment: If you have a request for a PHP file the session timeout will be reset, so it is 1440 seconds (or whatever the value of `ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime')` is) again, if you want for example have a javascript timer counting down.